# Monotouch uitable with custom cell too slowly

Tags: c#, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have the following code for my table and my custom cell:

Here is the code of my viewcontroller

```cs
public void SearchHotel (){

            Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
            var distribution = new HotelDistribution[]{new HotelDistribution(){ Adults = 1, Children = 0, ChildrenAges = new int[0]} };
            var items = hotel.SearchHotels(Convert.ToDateTime("2013-08-08"),Convert.ToDateTime("2013-09-09 "),"(MIA)", distribution,"","","",0);


            List<DtoHotelinformation> data = new List<DtoHotelinformation>();

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                DtoHotelinformation DtoHotelinformation = new DtoHotelinformation();
                DtoHotelinformation.price  = item.Price.ToString();
                DtoHotelinformation.title =  item.Name.ToString();
                DtoHotelinformation.subtitle = item.Address.ToString();
                DtoHotelinformation.price = item.Price.ToString();
                DtoHotelinformation.imageUlr = item.ImageUrl;

                data.Add(DtoHotelinformation);
            }

            hud.Hide(true);
            hud.RemoveFromSuperview();
            HotelSearchTable.Source = new HotelTableSource(data.ToArray());
            HotelSearchTable.ReloadData();

        }
```

Here is the code of my tablesource

```cs
    public class HotelTableSource : UITableViewSource
    {

        DtoHotelinformation[] tableItems;
        NSString cellIdentifier = new NSString("TableCell");

        public HotelTableSource (DtoHotelinformation[] items)
        {
            tableItems = items;
        }
        public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
        {
            return tableItems.Length;
        }

        public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            new UIAlertView("Row Selected", tableItems[indexPath.Row].title, null, "OK", null).Show();
            tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true); // normal iOS behaviour is to remove the blue highlight
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            CustomCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(cellIdentifier) as CustomCell;
            if (cell == null)
                cell = new CustomCell(cellIdentifier);
            cell.UpdateCell(tableItems[indexPath.Row].title, tableItems[indexPath.Row].subtitle, tableItems[indexPath.Row].price,
                            tableItems[indexPath.Row].imageUlr );
            return cell;


        }

        public override float GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return 60;
        }
    }
}
```

here is the customcell code:

```cs
public class CustomCell : UITableViewCell
{
    UILabel headingLabel, subheadingLabel, priceLabel;
    UIImageView imageService;
    UIImageView star, star2, star3, star4, star5;
    public CustomCell (NSString cellId) : base (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
    {
        imageService = new UIImageView();
        star   = new UIImageView();
        star2  = new UIImageView();
        star3  = new UIImageView();
        star4  = new UIImageView();
        star5  = new UIImageView();
        headingLabel = new UILabel(){
            Font = UIFont.FromName("Verdana-Bold", 14f),
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear,
            TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(241, 241, 211)
        };
        subheadingLabel = new UILabel(){
            Font = UIFont.FromName("Verdana-Bold", 8f),
            TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(60, 0, 100),
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
        };
        priceLabel = new UILabel(){
            Font = UIFont.FromName("Verdana", 14f),
            TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(241, 241, 211),
            BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
        };
            AddSubview(imageService);
        AddSubview(headingLabel);
        AddSubview(subheadingLabel);
        AddSubview(priceLabel);

    }

    public void UpdateCell (string title, string subtitle, string price, string imageUlr )
    {
        if (imageUlr != null) {
            NSUrl nsUrl = new NSUrl(imageUlr);
            NSData data = NSData.FromUrl(nsUrl);
            imageService.Image = new UIImage(data);
        } else {
            imageService.Image = UIImage.FromFile("generic_no_image_tiny.jpg");
        }

        headingLabel.Text = title;
        subheadingLabel.Text = subtitle;
        priceLabel.Text = price;

    }



    public override void LayoutSubviews ()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews ();
        imageService.Frame = new RectangleF(10, 10, 50, 33);
        headingLabel.Frame = new RectangleF(70, 4, 220, 25);
        subheadingLabel.Frame = new RectangleF(100, 30, 100, 20);
        priceLabel.Frame = new RectangleF(250, 30, 100, 20);
    }
}
```

The table works well, I get the data I need, but it's works extremely slow. I mean when I try to scroll the table everything move very slowly.Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was the image, here is how a solve the problem using MonoTouch.Dialog.Utilities.ImageLoader

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using MonoTouch.Dialog.Utilities;

namespace Zurfers.Mobile.iOS
{
    public class CustomCell : UITableViewCell, IImageUpdated
    {
        UILabel headingLabel, subheadingLabel, priceLabel;
        UIImageView imageService;
        UIImageView star, star2, star3, star4, star5;
        public CustomCell (NSString cellId) : base (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellId)
        {
            imageService = new UIImageView();
            star   = new UIImageView();
            star2  = new UIImageView();
            star3  = new UIImageView();
            star4  = new UIImageView();
            star5  = new UIImageView();
            headingLabel = new UILabel(){
                Font = UIFont.FromName("Verdana-Bold", 14f),
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear,
                TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(241, 241, 211)
            };
            subheadingLabel = new UILabel(){
                Font = UIFont.FromName("Verdana-Bold", 8f),
                TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(255, 255, 255),
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
            };
            priceLabel = new UILabel(){
                Font = UIFont.FromName("Verdana", 14f),
                TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(241, 241, 211),
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear
            };

            AddSubview(imageService);
            AddSubview(headingLabel);
            AddSubview(subheadingLabel);
            AddSubview(priceLabel);
            AddSubview(star);
            AddSubview(star2);
            AddSubview(star3);
            AddSubview(star4);
            AddSubview(star5);

        }

        public void UpdateCell (string title, string subtitle, string price, string imageUlr, string rating )
        {
            if (imageUlr != null) {
                var u = new Uri(imageUlr);
                ImageLoader MyLoader= new ImageLoader(50,50);
                imageService.Image = MyLoader.RequestImage(u,this);

            } else {
                imageService.Image = UIImage.FromFile("generic_no_image_tiny.jpg");
            }


            headingLabel.Text = title;
            subheadingLabel.Text = subtitle;
            if (subtitle.Length > 40) {
                subheadingLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
                subheadingLabel.Lines = 0;
            }

            switch (rating) {
                case "T":
                    star.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star2.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    break;
                case "S":
                    star.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star2.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star3.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    break;
                case "F":
                    star.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star2.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star3.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star4.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    break;
                case "L":
                    star.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star2.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star3.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star4.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    star5.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ZurfersMovil-Stars.png");
                    break;
            }


            priceLabel.Text = "USD" + price;
            priceLabel.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize (16);
        }


        public void UpdatedImage (Uri uri)
        {
            imageService.Image = ImageLoader.DefaultRequestImage(uri, this);
        }


        public override void LayoutSubviews ()
        {
            base.LayoutSubviews ();
            imageService.Frame = new RectangleF(10, 10, 50, 33);
            headingLabel.Frame = new RectangleF(70, 4, 240, 25);
            subheadingLabel.Frame = new RectangleF(70, 25, 240, 20);
            priceLabel.Frame = new RectangleF(220, 45, 100, 20);
            star.Frame = new RectangleF(70, 45, 15, 15);
            star2.Frame = new RectangleF(85, 45, 15, 15);
            star3.Frame = new RectangleF(100, 45, 15, 15);
            star4.Frame = new RectangleF(115, 45, 15, 15);
            star5.Frame = new RectangleF(130, 45, 15, 15);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Do **not** override `GetHeightForRow` to return a constant value. Instead set the `RowHeight` property of `UITableView` to constant value you need to display your cells.

The reason behind this is that when you override `GetHeightForRow` iOS `UITableView` will need to query it for **each** cell to compute the total height. That very slow (at best) and unusable once you have thousands of potential cells.

Comment: Thanks, but where do I have to set this property.

Comment: I think you have other issues as well. E.g. you're adding subviews each time you update a cell - but when are they removed ? i.e. cell are reused (and will already have the subviews). For performance issues you better use a tool, like Apple Instruments, to find where the time is being spent, fix it and repeat that process until your application performance match your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid allocation of objects that may be big and are easily reusable. Here you are creating an UIImage each time you are going to display the cell. Even worse, you are probably opening a file, reading it and decompressing it to then create the displayable UIImage. You should use a cache for avoiding duplicate instances of the same UIImage. This little class should do the work:

```cs
public class ImageCache {
    private Dictionary<string, UIImage> cache = new Dictionary<string, UIImage>();
    public static readonly ImageCache SharedInstance = new ImageCache();

    public ImageCache() {
    }

    private UIImage ImageForUrl(string url) {
        UIImage image = null;

        if (!this.cache.TryGetValue(url, out image)) {
            NSUrl url = new NSUrl(url);
            NSData data = NSData.FromUrl(url);
            image = UIImage.FromData(data);
            if (image != null) {
                this.cache[url] = image;
            }
        }

        return image;
    }

    public UIImage this[string url] {
        get { return this.ImageForUrl(url); }
    }
}
```

I just wrote it and haven't tried it but it should do the trick. Use it like

```cs
UIImage image = ImageCache.SharedInstance["blabla.png"];
```

Note: There is also the bug that poupou explained where you are adding the views each time you are updating.

Comment: rFlex, thank...I update my code and use your class, but I still have the same problem. But the problem it's the image.